# Autowire setters using StructureMap

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Let's say I have the following:

```
public interface IDoStuff 

public class DoerOfStuff : IDoStuff

public class RandomClass
{
    public IDoStuff Doer {get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Assuming `RandomClass` has only a default constructor (and we'd like to keep it that way) my questions are:

1. How can I bootstrap StructureMap so that the `Doer` in `RandomClass` get autowired to `DoerOfStuff`?
2. How can I make it more generic, such that any class that has an `IDoStuff` property gets autowired to `DoerOfStuff`?
3. How can I make `DoerOfStuff` a Singleton?

Thanks in advance!

Note: I assume this is possible with StructureMap so ideally the answer will show that.  If for some reason you know it isn't though, please feel free to show how you'd do it with a different container.

Cheers,
-Sean

---

**EDIT :**
Here is how I was able to get it working:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<IDoStuff>().Singleton().Use<DoerOfStuff>();
    x.SetAllProperties(policy => policy.TypeMatches(type => type == typeof(IDoStuff)));
    // this works too
    // x.FillAllPropertiesOfType<IDoStuff>();
});
```

In either case though, this only worked if I also added the following:

```
public RandomClass()
{
    ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this);
}
```

I am still curious if I can skip the `BuildUp()` somehow though.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Container(x => {
 x.For<IDoStuff>().Singleton().Use<DoerOfStuff>();
 x. FillAllPropertiesOfType<IDoStuff>();
})
```

Comment: Since Doer is a property, isn't it also required to run IContainer.BuildUp() on the RandomClass object after it's been created to initialize the properties?

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me, I get a null reference.  If I do an ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDoStuff> it works though, so I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: The only way I was able to get this to work was to add the ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this); to the RandomClass (see my edit).  If you add that to your answer or show me how I don't need it I will gladly accept your answer.