# Property injection not working when using StructureMap and NServiceBus

Tags: structuremap, nservicebus

I've installed the `NServiceBus.StructureMap` package from NuGet and property injection is no longer working on my Sagas. Here's my configuration code (using the generic host):

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            .StructureMapBuilder(ConfigureStructureMap())
            .XmlSerializer();
    }

    private static IContainer ConfigureStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.For<IBarcodeReader>().Use<DataMatrixBarcodeReader>();
            cfg.ForSingletonOf<IDocumentStore>().Use(() => InitializeStore());
            cfg.For<IDocumentSession>().Use(x => x.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession());
        });

        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }

    private static IDocumentStore InitializeStore()
    {
        return new DocumentStore
        {
            Url = "http://localhost:8080/",
            DefaultDatabase = "db"
        }
        .Initialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setter injection is not on by default in StructureMap so you need to enable it [Autowire setters using StructureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634808/autowire-setters-using-structuremap)